# Sanitize string from Malicious Markdown Vectors in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, xss

What can I use to sanitize string from Malicious Markdown Vectors before storing it in database?

I am using spring boot on back-end, and I need somehow to sanitize string before it is saved in database and later used for Cross-Site Scripting attacks. This is example of Malicious Markdown:

`[clickme](javascript:prompt(document.domain))`

After it's saved, it's shown as link and can be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

[OWASP](https://owasp.org/) is the oldest library out there for preventing this or any other kind of malicious user inputs, for your case [here](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) is the page you need to go over.

Here is an example

```
var sanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();
var html = @"<script>alert('xss')</script><div onload=""alert('xss')"""
    + @"style=""background-color: test"">Test<img src=""test.gif"""
    + @"style=""background-image: url(javascript:alert('xss')); margin: 10px""></div>";
var sanitized = sanitizer.Sanitize(html, "http://www.example.com");
Assert.That(sanitized, Is.EqualTo(@"<div style=""background-color: test"">"
    + @"Test<img style=""margin: 10px"" src=""http://www.example.com/test.gif""></div>"));
```

Please check web application firewall too https://owasp.org/www-community/Web_Application_Firewall